# What technology should I use to synchronize Windows PC with Android mobile phone

Tags: android, synchronization

I'm trying to write a program, which allows me to get a live feed from the phone camera on Windows PC.(What technology is the most suitable for this task ).

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi is the best bet. Bluetooth might also work with SPP. USB is a non-starter.

Comment: Ok. Let's suppose I would like to use Wi-Fi and Java. Does anyone knows any library or framework that might come in handy?